# Solarium 3.2.0 create ping for SOLR5.0

Tags: solr

Installed SOLR 5.0 and started the SOLR instance with `bin/solr start -e cloud`... normal stuff. The web UI is functioning and can see the two nodes.

Created an index file trying to ping the server per Solarium documentation:

```
require_once ('init.php');
$str="Running Solarium client version: ".Solarium\Client::VERSION;

$client = new Solarium\Client($config);
// create a ping query
$ping = $client->createPing();
var_dump($ping);

// execute the ping query
try {
    $result = $client->ping($ping);
    $str=$str.'Ping query successful';
    var_dump($result->getData());
} catch (Solarium\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Ping query failed';
}
return $str;
```

the $str can show using Solarium client version 3.2.0.

But while doing `$client->ping()`, there is an exception:

```
Problem accessing /solr/admin/ping. Reason:
Not Found
```

Any hints???

`config.php` pasted here:

```
<?php
$config = array(
    'endpoint' => array(
        'localhost' => array(
            'host' => '10.0.0.8',
            'port' => 8983,
            'path' => '/solr/',
        )
    )
);
```

It is a remote connection.

Comment: Would appreciate any hints, views on this particular issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Put collection name in config.php like this:

```
'path' => '/solr/collection_name/',
```